# Shutdowns just hangs sometimes (CPU cooler and keyboard backlight on)

Tags: arch-linux, shutdown

I'm using an Arch-based distribution called EndeavourOS. I asked [here](https://forum.endeavouros.com/t/shutdown-turn-off-screen-but-keyboard-backlight-keeps-on-endeavouros-gnome/40921) the same question and thought it was solved but today happened again ...

Basically, I clicked on **shutdown** in XFCE (previously, I was using GNOME), and it displayed all the shutdown logs. The screen turned off, but the CPU cooler and keyboard backlight remained active. In order to shut it down completely, I have to hold the power button or use the Magic SysRq Key. If I don't do that, it will stay powered on all day (I have already tested this)

[Here](http://ix.io/4yrq) I've the output of `sudo journalctl -b -1 | eos-sendlog` but I don´t know what could be wrong.